# Align Component to Row End and Dynamically Modify its Width Based on Text Size

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

In the use case, I have a row with two elements, and the width of the first component should adjust based on the width of the second component. Additionally, the width of the second component needs to be defined dynamically based on the size of the text, which can vary depending on the supported languages.
I have tried the below approach

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        .wrapContentHeight()
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    val firstElementWidthBasedOnSecondComponentTextSize = if (uiModel.buttonText.length > 12) 0.5f else 0.6f
    Text(
        text = "Some Text",
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 16.dp)
            .align(alignment = Alignment.Start)
            .fillMaxWidth(firstElementWidthBasedOnSecondComponentTextSize),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
    )
    Button(
        onClick = { },
        modifier = modifier.wrapContentWidth(),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(30.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Android Community", // this can be one/two/three words on different languages
            maxLines = 1,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        )
    }
}
```

### Example

If Button Text= **Android**
[image]

If Button Text = **Android Community**
[image]

The above solution works but the `firstElementWidthBasedOnSecondComponentTextSize` is based on the text size & it is not a good approach, ad using the same approach does not make sense on big screens as it'll already have enough space.

My Question: **Are there any other ways to approach this use case?**

Comment: It is not clear what is the expectation. Kindly add more info. There is code, screenshot, and explanation of how it works, but info missing on how it should be changed.